# How do I make a small box similar to the one in the attached picture with a full view of an area?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layouts, maps

So I have one area that's been split into 7 layouts, how do I make a similar full layout view as show in the attached picture?

[image]

Comment: You are using Data Driven Pages?

Comment: No, I'm not. I will look into it. Cheers

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Comment: I'm using ArcGIS Pro.